# Elasticsearch NEST Library

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We need to create facets in a field which is an array of int [1,2,3,4,5,6].
If we map this field as Text, Elasticsearch throws an exception. If we mark it as Keyword we don't get all the individual items in the facet.

How can this be achieved with the NEST library (version 5)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Map it as an integer. [NEST's automapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html) will infer an integer mapping for it by default

Given the following type

```
public class Message
{
    public int[] Integers { get; set; }
}
```

Automapping would look like

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

client.CreateIndex("messages", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Message>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

which produces the following mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "message": {
      "properties": {
        "integers": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [attribute mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html) if you want to explicitly control the mapping

```
public class Message
{
    [Number(NumberType.Integer)]
    public int[] Integers { get; set; }
}
var client = new ElasticClient();

client.CreateIndex("messages", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Message>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

Or [fluent mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html) if you prefer to keep mapping separate from your POCOs

```
client.CreateIndex(messagesIndex, c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Message>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Number(n => n
                    .Name(nn => nn.Integers)
                    .Type(NumberType.Integer)
                )           
            )
        )
    )
);
```

or using the [scalar method](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-5-0-released#say-heya-to-the-all-new-scalar-property)

```
client.CreateIndex(messagesIndex, c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Message>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Scalar(n => n.Integers)            
            )
        )
    )
);
```

With the mapping in place, faceting on integer values would look like

```
client.IndexMany(new[] {
    new Message { Integers = new [] { 1, 2, 3 } },
    new Message { Integers = new [] { 3, 4, 5 } },
    new Message { Integers = new [] { 1, 4, 5 } },
});

client.Refresh(messagesIndex);

var searchResponse = client.Search<Message>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("ints", t => t
            .Field(f => f.Integers)
        )
    )
);

foreach (var bucket in searchResponse.Aggs.Terms<int>("ints").Buckets)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{bucket.Key}:{bucket.DocCount}");
}
```

which yields

```
1:2
3:2
4:2
5:2
2:1
```